# Как открыть HTML-страницу в Делфи?

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-7

Как открыть HTML-страницу в Делфи?

Comment: `TWebBrowser` вам в помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Если имеется в виду **в браузере**, то:

```
uses ShellAPI;
..
ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(HomeURL), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

---

Если **внутри формы**, то TWEBBrowser. Это компонент со вкладки Internet, модуль SHDocVw.

Переход по ссылке делается так:

```
WebBrowser.Navigate(HomeURL);
```